# Multiple stock symbols for same company with in USA

Tags: united-states, stocks, trading, cusip

I was looking for a quote (and trading) for Berkshire Hathaway Inc class B . There are web sites that are displaying the following symbols

- BRK'B
- NYSE: BRK.B
- BRK-B

Why so many and what about ACATS from one brokerage to another if they use different symbol for same company ?

Comment: Since they all have "BRK" and "B", I'm betting that different brokerages' computer systems have different separators.  Interesting question, though.

Comment: seems similar question is there https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90498

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are symbols for shares not unique across markets?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/90498/why-are-symbols-for-shares-not-unique-across-markets)

Comment: Variation of symbols across different markets in different countries (the links  provided) is not the same as different symbols  for a single stock on one exchange (this question).

Comment: @md-tech My question is for same company with in USA

Comment: @puzzled the US still has separate exchanges and data companies with separate histories. In fact if you read my answer on the duplicate question carefully you will see that outside of the US ISIN has become something of a standard where as the US is reluctant to enter into that standard. This causes me issues daily in my job

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nomenclature for stock symbols isn't standardized.  Brokers and web sites use a variety of suffixes for non standard symbols.  This is particularly maddening for  preferred stocks. Fortunately, securities have CUSIP numbers so that other than infrequent human error, ACAT transfers operate efficiently.

To demonstrate the insanity of web site nomenclature for preferred stocks, here's an example for an Alabama Power preferred stock:

```
 QuantumOnline     -       ALP-Q    
 S&P               -       ALP-Q    
 NYSE              PR      ALPPRQ   
 NYSE Amex         p       ALPpQ    
 Bloomberg        /P       ALP/PQ   
 Charles Schwab   /PR      ALP/PRQ    
 E-Trade           p       ALPpQ    
 Fidelity          PR      ALPPRQ   
 Google Finance    -       ALP-Q    
 JPMorgan          PR      ALP PRQ  
 LPL Financial     '       ALP'Q        
 MarketWatch      .PR      ALP.PRQ  
 Quicken           PR      ALP PRQ  
 TD Ameritrade     -       ALP-Q    
 Vanguard         _p       ALP_pQ   
 Yahoo!           -p       ALP-pQ
```

Comment: is USA using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number

Comment: How did you obtain this list of preferred stock ticker symbols?

Comment: I've owned as well as traded preferred stocks for 20+ years.  I've had accounts or used the web sites of 11 of the above.  Along the way I found this list somewhere, perhaps at QuantumOnline.  Some of them may be out of date.