# What do these symbols in preferred shares description mean?

Tags: preferred-stocks

What does this symbols in preferred shares description mean?
[image]

- DEP SHS : Depositary Shares?
- RP : Redemption Price?
- NCUM = Non Cumulative
- PF : preferred?
- CLBL =  Callable
- PFD: preferred ?
- Perpetual ?
- (EXC 3/21 G6359F137) ?
- JNR : Junior preferred share ?
- SUB: subordinated
- DEB : Debenture?
- CONV DUE: Does it mean that the preferred share will be converted to common stocks?
- RED = Redemption ?
- REP = Redeemable ?
- LP : Liquidation Preference ?
- LTD : limited life preferred shares
- FLTG : Floating rate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nomenclature for preferred stock symbols isn't standardized. Brokers and web sites use a variety of suffixes for non standard symbols. [Read this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/115378/multiple-stock-symbols-for-same-company-with-in-usa/115379#115379) for details.

In your list, the lower case "p" means that it is a preferred stock.

As for the meaning of the terms that you listed, Quantum Online is an excellent source for preferred stock information.  [This page](https://www.quantumonline.com/glossary.cfm) provides definitions of such terms.